# How to login in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I have a session scoped managed bean with name 'usermanager'.  i want to store user information which is newly logged in , in a property of usermanager  bean and access it using  static metod below. I want to ask  these questions ,thanks in advance and sorry for poor english.

1-A managed bean is managed if i get it throught jsf injection mechanizm.That is if i create a instance using  new UserManager() this will not be a managed bean .Am i right?

2-In what conditions usermanager in code below can be null.

3-What is the most efficient way of handling user,group permissions in java .Should i use  Spring ,Seam  for this purpose.

4-Should i store this user info in Httpsession with setParamater(key,Object) or continue to store it in a session bean.

```
  public static User getUserOfCurrentSession(){
         UserManager userManager = (UserManager) ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession(true)
                .getAttribute("userManager");

         if(userManager!=null){
             return userManager.getUser();
         }
        FacesContext c = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest r = (HttpServletRequest) c.getExternalContext()
                .getRequest();
        HttpSession s = r.getSession(false);
        if(s!=null)
          s.invalidate();
        try{
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("login.xhtml");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        return  null;
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw  new RuntimeException("Un authonticated  user action");
    }
```

Comment: Getting the raw Servlet API in JSF is a strong "code smell" indicator. So also in this particular case. Learn about managed property injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you are right. You must leave JSF instantiate the bean for it to be managed
2. If there is no session attribute (or bean) called `userManager`. But you better get this instance through injection.
3. There is no "most efficient way". It depends on your requirements. I have often done it manually, because it was simple enough. If it is more complex - spring security is said to be good (though I'm reserved).
4. It goes in the session either way, so prefer the bean.